# xcode getting quit while generate ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

my xcode version is 7.0.1, Now my client gave me their p12, .provision. Now i added all the under build setting. i want to generate ipa file to upload in app store. So i select first option in below image and i dont have my client developer account. So i choose "local assign assets"..After that my xcode getting quit automatically

[image]

My client gave me these files :

1.p12
2. projectname.mobileprovision

Does `.cer` is needed to generate ipa file to upload in app store.

Please help me !!1

Comment: Click on save For Adhoc Deployment.

Comment: yes i did that also the warning showing no provision profile for this Adhoc development

Comment: Have u added UDID and taken the provisioning profile. have u added P12 in Keychain Access?

Comment: p12 added. this is distribution know to upload in app store. So in my provision profile no udid is added

Comment: yes i open my .provision profile in text edit its added with one udid

Comment: check the link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812

Comment: to upload ipa in app store and to generate ipa file should i select first option or adhoc deployment??

Comment: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F   login here add follow instructions then here u need to upload ..

Answer (score 1):

The Keychain Access Window opens up. With the Keychain Access window open, go up to the Keychain Access menu at the top and select File and then click on Import Items. Another window will appear. In this window, you should browse to the [.p12 or .pfx certificate](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/p12-import-export-mac-server.htm) file on your computer.

& After [upload process](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html)...

Refer this tutorial and testflight app information...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Any solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi

Answer (score 1):

You can't create .ipa file when following issue arise.

1) if provisional certificate not made properly.

or

2) created provisional certi. and installed certificate is not match.

or

3) when proper team is not selected in project and target tab.

or

4) certificate make issue for Adhoc or developement (AppStore).

you can check what issue is in your end of given here.

Comment: to upload in app store what should i select. Adhoc or first option  in my above image???

Comment: Appstore deployment....you can select Adhoc while you want to share app to your client whose UDID is registerd with apple id.

Comment: if its helps then please appreciate by give +1.

Comment: my client have rights to upload in app store . So he sended me provison profie ,p12. And no udid is registred in that provision profile. i need to generate ipa file and  have to send my client. so he will upload in app store.

Comment: if you want to see your application to your client that you have created then you can use testflight app for the same.. you can get separate tutorial for how to share application using testflight.

Comment: please get my point.. he need only ipa file not for testing. I need to generate ipa file and i have to send him . he will upload to app store

Comment: ok. then install that provisioning profile by double click and then make archive with selecting first option in image that you have post here.

Comment: Any solution please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251141/swipe-left-or-right-to-load-the-view-controller-with-the-collection-view-cell-hi