# Swipe left or right to load the view controller with the collection view cell highlight

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swipe-gesture

I have 3 view controllers called `firstvc, secondvc, thirdvc`. And I have one collection view which will scroll horizontally. If i select my `first cell` my `firstvc` wil disply in my sub view on my `mainviewcontroller`. Its same for `2, 3rd cell` too. Its fine .

Now i need one functionality like, if i swipe my `subview` which will have all my view controllers when i am selecting any cell. I need to add swipe left or right.

For example :

if i am in `firstvc` then my `first cell` will be **selected** . Now if i swipe my `subview` to right my `secondvc` have to come mean while my second cell of collection view also have to `highlight`

I dont know how to applay.

**my code :**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var contentSubView: UIView!
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
       // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project

        var borderColor: UIColor! = UIColor.clear
        //var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath{
            borderColor = UIColor.red
            //borderWidth = 1 //or whatever you please
        }else{
            borderColor = UIColor.white
           // borderWidth = 0
        }

        cell.myview.backgroundColor = borderColor
       // cell.myview.layer.borderWidth = borderColor

        return cell
    }


    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

        //based on your comment remove the subviews before add on your myview
        //let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        selectedIndexPath = indexPath

        for subview in contentSubView.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let alertStoryBoard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var controller: UIViewController!

        if indexPath.item == 0 {

            if  let allCollectionViewController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"firstvc") as? firstvc  {

                controller = allCollectionViewController
            }

        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {

            if  let allCollec = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"secondvc") as? secondvc  {
                controller = allCollec
            }


        }else if indexPath.item == 2 {


            if  let wController = alertStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"Thirdvc") as? Thirdvc  {
                controller = wController
            }

        }

        addChildViewController(controller)

        // Add the child's View as a subview
        contentSubView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.view.frame = contentSubView.bounds
        controller.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // tell the childviewcontroller it's contained in it's parent
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
```

My full project zip :   https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: link is not active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the main view controller's view.
The main view controller would be responsible for managing the gesture's calls

#### Basically in code:

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let swipeToLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changePageOnSwipe(_:)))
let swipeToRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changePageOnSwipe(_:)))
swipeToLeft.direction = .right 
swipeToRight.direction = .left
self.contentSubView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToLeft) // Gesture are added to the top view that should handle them
self.contentSubView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeToRight)
```

Since you will have to move from a VC at an index to another index you might need a property for keeping track of the currently selected view controller:

```
var currentIndexPath: IndexPath?
```

And you can change the value of it each time a new VC is selected. So:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    self.currentIndexPath = indexPath
    // ... Other settings
}
```

add the `changePageOnSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)` method in your main ViewController. Since it is the "chief" view controller who possesses the `collectionView`, it will handle the swipes and tell its children to appear:

```
func changePageOnSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let indexPath = self.currentIndexPath else {
        // When the page loads and there is no current selected VC, the swipe will not work
        // unless you set an initial value for self.currentIndexPath
        return
    }

    var newIndex = indexPath    // if self.collectionview.indexPathsForSelectedItems is not empty, you can also use it instead of having a self.currentIndexPath property 

    // move in the opposite direction for the movement to be intuitive
    // So swiping " <-- " should show index on the right (row + 1)
    if gesture.direction == .left {
        newIndex = IndexPath(row: newIndex.row+1, section: newIndex.section)
    } else {
        newIndex = IndexPath(row: newIndex.row-1, section: self.currentIndexPath!.section)
    }

    if canPresentPageAt(indexPath: newIndex) {
        // Programmatically select the item and make the collectionView scroll to the correct number
        self.collectionview.selectItem(at: newIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
        // The delegate method is not automatically called when you select programmatically
        self.collectionView(self.collectionview, didSelectItemAt: newIndex!)
    } else {
        // Do something when the landing page is invalid (like if the swipe would got to page at index -1 ...)
        // You could choose to direct the user to the opposite side of the collection view (like the VC at index self.items.count-1
        print("You are tying to navigate to an invalid page")
    }
}
```

and since you are doing the swipe programmatically, you have to make sure that the swipe is **valid** before trying to actually move. You have to **add safety checks**:

```
/** You can use an helper method for those checks
 */
func canPresentPageAt(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Do necessary checks to ensure that the user can indeed go to the desired page
    // Like: check if you have a non-nil ViewController at the given index. (If you haven't implemented index 3,4,5,... it should return false)
    //
    // This method can be called either from a swipe
    // or another way when you need it
    if indexPath.row < 0 || indexPath.row >= self.items.count {
        print("You are trying to go to a non existing page")
        return false
    } else {
        print("If you haven't implemented a VC for page 4 it will crash here")
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can set a default indexPath for `self.currentIndexPath` in `viewDidLoad` so that the user can already swipe when he lands on your main VC without having selected another VC in the collectionView.

---

Note:  If you happen to have gesture recognisers in the sub-ViewControllers, some gestures may conflict and you would have to learn how to resolve such conflicts with delegate methods such as `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOf:)`.

Comment: TRied ur solution but its crashing, once i swipe start from first vc to second , second to third , third to again second, second to first , then if i try to swipe further left ..then its crashing..same for last view controller and if i try to swipe more that time also crashing ...here that project zip :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: Yes it does not add checks to ensure you can swipe to the desired location. The collectionView does that for you, but when you do things programmatically (with a function call) you have to make checks by yourself. In particular, you have to check that the landing page would be valid AND that you have implemented it. In particular, you have not implemented page 4 so it crashes when swiping to go to page 4 (as it crashes when you click on "4" within your collectionView)

Comment: Now how can i handle that....like can i set in my colelction view `did select method or changePageOnSwipe` . How can i resolve that crash...

Comment: THE CRASH on tis line ` self.collectionview.selectItem(at: newIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)`

Comment: This is that final project zip that i tried https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0

Comment: If i m in first vc then i further swipe left ist crashing, same for if i am in last vc then if i swipe right then alos its crashing...please help me out..

Comment: I forgot to mention it but did you use the updated answer ? To remove the crash with the swipe, use the updated answer.  **and** (of course) remove some numbers in your `var items = ["1","2","3"]` since you do not have a VC for pages above 3. This is why the example app also crashes when you *tap* on numbers >= "4" in the collectionView.

Comment: HOW CAN I  set a default indexPath for self.currentIndexPath in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yah i removed those number if u check this link , its correctly setted to 3 no only. Here that updated proejct zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/fwj745kdgqvgjxa/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0....And how I set a default indexPath for self.currentIndexPath in viewDidLoad

Comment: No, new problem. after i update ur solution. if i m in first vc then if i swipe right i was not able to swipe to second vc. in my log i m getting `You are trying to go to a non existing page
You are tying to navigate to an invalid page`

Comment: this is that final updated answer project zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdf245mfsxlm93e/Collection%20view%20example.zip?dl=0 please look in to that and give me some solution..its struck me more here

Comment: Also one more : when ever open my project its black. I want my first vc to be place first in my subview of my `mainviewcontroler` And also my first cell have to be heigh lighted....If i found solution for this also...it will be a great help from you,,,i can learn some thing from that...

Comment: `currentIndexPath` has type `IndexPath?` *not Array* so why do you assign an array to it  ( `= []` ) ? You have to remove the `= []`.  If you want a default value for it, use the **initializer** of the `IndexPath` class.  Either in `var currentIndexPath: IndexPath?   = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` or in `viewDidLoad() { /* ... */ self.currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0); }`

Comment: That index path i used like this `array to it ( = [] ) ? `  which will help me high light the cell border color, when when ever i change to any view controller, it will also chnage. so only i did like that.

Comment: No in view did load i did like `self.currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0).. so my first cell of my colelction view is high lighted. But in my sub view of my `miainviewcontroller` ist not showing the first vc, Still ist showing the balck. If  select first cell then only its showing...Only this issue i have now

Comment: For your last question, how do you think you should do it ? Look at the methods I use in the `changePageOnSwipe()` method. [collectionView.selectItem(at ...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618057-selectitem) and `self.didSelect...` which is a [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154588/discussion-between-jmm-and-spikesa).